# I want to create a bot that can open my bluestacks app player , then install apps to open various apps and then finally close bluestacks .

Tags: android, bots

The bot should be able to perform simple tasks like opening some apps , uninstalling apps , clearing defaults and so on . I`m new to botting so from where I can learn such things . Thanks

Comment: "where I can learn such things" => certainly not here, as this type of question is way to broad for StackOverflow, we focus on specific programming issues. You probably want to look for a book or tutorial, and break down what you want in smaller tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Bluestacks + bstweaker + root + modified bs kernel (enable android serial) + phone profiles. All that should be automated with Clickermann/Autoit scripts. Bot size is about 2,3 gb. Good luck, man ;)